# W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value array of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

I'm getting floored by this error. I'm retrieving a JSON Object to display in a recyclerview in Android Studio. I've made some changes based on previous answers here, but it seems not to make a difference.

The code receives a JSON Object with a nested JSON array ("data"), containing a list of receipts.

Example JSON

```
{
  "status": true,
  "message": "Data fetched successfully",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "receipt_id": "2",
      "parent_id": "0",
      "has_children": "0",
      "product_id": "4",
      "product_code": "24904",
      "product_name": "LIGHT SOLAR S/STEEL GLASS LENS COLOUR CHANGE PDQ H25.5CM",
      "quantity_expected": "120",
      "quantity_received": "120",
      "quantity_putaway": "120",
      "quantity_held": "0",
      "reason_held": "",
      "unit_quantity": "0",
      "subinner_uom": "",
      "subinner_quantity": "0",
      "subinner_unit_quantity": "0",
      "subinner_weight": "0.000",
      "subinner_cubic": "0.000000",
      "inner_uom": "",
      "inner_quantity": "0",
      "inner_unit_quantity": "0",
      "inner_weight": "0.000",
      "inner_cubic": "0.000000",
      "outer_expected": "10",
      "outer_uom": "CTN",
      "outer_quantity": "10",
      "outer_unit_quantity": "12",
      "outer_weight": "0.000",
      "outer_cubic": "0.000000",
      "outer_length": "0.000",
      "outer_width": "0.000",
      "outer_height": "0.000",
      "pallet_uom": "",
      "pallet_quantity": "0",
      "pallet_unit_quantity": "0",
      "pallet_weight": "0.000",
      "pallet_cubic": "0.000000",
      "batch_number": " ",
      "date_expiry": "0000-00-00",
      "serial_number": "",
      "length": "36.000",
      "width": "29.000",
      "height": "29.000",
      "cubic": "0.030276",
      "weight": "3.000",
      "barcode": "",
      "cost_current": "0.00",
      "status": "0",
      "is_uniform_pallet": "0",
      "pallet_id": "",
      "is_checked": "1",
      "is_putaway": "1",
      "location_id": "1757",
      "last_location": "10139",
      "split_key": "V09AFONYL7",
      "created_by": "9",
      "modified_by": "6",
      "datetime_created": "2019-08-13 12:11:06",
      "datetime_modified": "2019-08-14 16:58:52"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "receipt_id": "2",
      "parent_id": "0",
      "has_children": "0",
      "product_id": "3",
      "product_code": "24900",
      "product_name": "LIGHT SOLAR FAIRY WH LED PK100",
      "quantity_expected": "1008",
      "quantity_received": "1008",
      "quantity_putaway": "1008",
      "quantity_held": "0",
      "reason_held": "",
      "unit_quantity": "0",
      "subinner_uom": "",
      "subinner_quantity": "0",
      "subinner_unit_quantity": "0",
      "subinner_weight": "0.000",
      "subinner_cubic": "0.000000",
      "inner_uom": "",
      "inner_quantity": "0",
      "inner_unit_quantity": "0",
      "inner_weight": "0.000",
      "inner_cubic": "0.000000",
      "outer_expected": "84",
      "outer_uom": "CTN",
      "outer_quantity": "84",
      "outer_unit_quantity": "12",
      "outer_weight": "0.000",
      "outer_cubic": "0.000000",
      "outer_length": "0.000",
      "outer_width": "0.000",
      "outer_height": "0.000",
      "pallet_uom": "",
      "pallet_quantity": "0",
      "pallet_unit_quantity": "0",
      "pallet_weight": "0.000",
      "pallet_cubic": "0.000000",
      "batch_number": " ",
      "date_expiry": "0000-00-00",
      "serial_number": "",
      "length": "36.000",
      "width": "23.000",
      "height": "23.000",
      "cubic": "0.019044",
      "weight": "3.500",
      "barcode": "",
      "cost_current": "0.00",
      "status": "0",
      "is_uniform_pallet": "0",
      "pallet_id": "",
      "is_checked": "1",
      "is_putaway": "1",
      "location_id": "1512",
      "last_location": "0",
      "split_key": "",
      "created_by": "9",
      "modified_by": "6",
      "datetime_created": "2019-08-13 12:11:06",
      "datetime_modified": "2019-08-14 16:58:52"
    },
```

Fetch JSON

```
private void fetchJSON(){

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ReceiptsLineInterface.JSONURL)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        ReceiptsLineInterface api = retrofit.create(ReceiptsLineInterface.class);

        Call<String> call = api.getString();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                Log.i("Responsestring", response.body());
                //Toast.makeText()
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        Log.i("onSuccess", response.body());
                        setRecyclerItems(response.body());
                    } else {
                        //Log.i("onEmptyResponse", "Returned empty response");//Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Nothing returned",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Code block with the errors

```
/**
     * Array list generator that should take JSON array from API query of Job
     * or Item list
     * @return items
     */
    public void setRecyclerItems(String response){

        try {
            //getting the whole json object from the response
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

            if(obj.optString("status").equals("true")){
                ArrayList<Receipts> modelRecyclerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                JSONArray dataArray  = obj.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {

                    Receipts modelRecycler = new Receipts();
                    JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    modelRecycler.setName(dataobj.getString("product_name"));
                    modelRecycler.setProductCode(dataobj.getString("product_code"));
                    modelRecycler.setReceiptID(dataobj.getString("receipt_id"));

                    modelRecyclerArrayList.add(modelRecycler);

                }

                retrofitAdapter = new RetrofitAdapter(this,modelRecyclerArrayList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(retrofitAdapter);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.optString("message")+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Logcat Response

```
2019-12-16 14:39:33.498 8562-8562/com.prostock.scanner I/onSuccess: array (
      'status' => true,
      'message' => 'Data fetched successfully',
      'data' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'id' => '1',
          'receipt_id' => '1',
          'parent_id' => '0',
          'has_children' => '0',
          'product_id' => '26',
          'product_code' => '57280',
          'product_name' => 'LIGHTS FAIRY CONNECTABLE 400',
          'quantity_expected' => '400',
          'quantity_received' => '400',
          'quantity_putaway' => '400',
          'quantity_held' => '0',
          'reason_held' => '',
          'unit_quantity' => '0',
          'subinner_uom' => '',
          'subinner_quantity' => '0',
          'subinner_unit_quantity' => '0',
          'subinner_weight' => '0.000',
          'subinner_cubic' => '0.000000',
          'inner_uom' => '',
          'inner_quantity' => '0',
          'inner_unit_quantity' => '0',
          'inner_weight' => '0.000',
          'inner_cubic' => '0.000000',
          'outer_expected' => '50',
          'outer_uom' => 'CTN',
          'outer_quantity' => '50',
          'outer_unit_quantity' => '8',
          'outer_weight' => '0.000',
          'outer_cubic' => '0.000000',
          'outer_length' => '0.000',
          'outer_width' => '0.000',
          'outer_height' => '0.000',
          'pallet_uom' => '',
          'pallet_quantity' => '0',
          'pallet_unit_quantity' => '0',
          'pallet_weight' => '0.000',
          'pallet_cubic' => '0.000000',
          'batch_number' => ' ',
          'date_expiry' => '0000-00-00',
          'serial_number' => '',
          'length' => '50.000',
          'width' => '22.000',
          'height' => '36.000',
          'cubic' => '0.039600',
          'weight' => '8.700',
          'barcode' => '',
          'cost_current' => '0.00',
          'status' => '0',
          'is_uniform_pallet' => '1',
          'pallet_id' => '',
          'is_checked' => '1',
          'is_putaway' => '1',
          'location_id' => '1641',
          'last_location' => '1562',
          'split_key' => '',
          'created_by' => '9',
          'modified_by' => '9',
          'datetime_created' => '2019-08-06 12:18:23',
          'datetime_modified' => '2019-08-06 16:30:34',
        ),
      ),
    )
2019-12-16 14:39:33.499 8562-8562/com.prostock.scanner W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value array of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
2019-12-16 14:39:33.499 8562-8562/com.prostock.scanner W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:112)
2019-12-16 14:39:33.499 8562-8562/com.prostock.scanner W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:163)
2019-12-16 14:39:33.499 8562-8562/com.prostock.scanner W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:176)
2019-12-16 14:39:33.499 8562-8562/com.prostock.scanner W/System.err:     at com.prostock.scanner.Activities.ScanSessionActivity.setRecyclerItems(ScanSessionActivity.java:154)
2019-12-16 14:39:33.499 8562-8562/com.prostock.scanner W/System.err:     at com.prostock.scanner.Activities.ScanSessionActivity$1.onResponse(ScanSessionActivity.java:130)
2019-12-16 14:39:33.499 8562-8562/com.prostock.scanner W/System.err:     at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:83)
2019-12-16 14:39:33.500 8562-8562/com.prostock.scanner W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
2019-12-16 14:39:33.500 8562-8562/com.prostock.scanner W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2019-12-16 14:39:33.500 8562-8562/com.prostock.scanner W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
2019-12-16 14:39:33.500 8562-8562/com.prostock.scanner W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
2019-12-16 14:39:33.500 8562-8562/com.prostock.scanner W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2019-12-16 14:39:33.500 8562-8562/com.prostock.scanner W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
2019-12-16 14:39:33.500 8562-8562/com.prostock.scanner W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: How are encoding Json in php, It seems the response is no a valid json

Comment: You can use Gson in parsing json to your custom list/object. https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone, I ended up finding the problem. My adapter was pointing to an extra endpoint. Works all good now!

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface ReceiptsLineInterface {

    String JSONURL = "http://[censored]/api/putaway/id/{receipts_line}/";

    @GET("WRONG ENDPOINT")
    Call<String> getString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that your JSON string response is malformed/contains extra characters that makes it an invalid JSON format. You should double check that you're sending the right UTF encoding from your server. Also, you should consider using a `GsonConverter` in your retrofit call. It will automatically box your response into your custom Java Object. So your retrofit instance will be replaced with:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ReceiptsLineInterface.JSONURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) // this line changed
                .build();
```

And the return type of your retrofit call would become: 
`Call<MyCustomObject>`

See this article for more details: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-adding-customizing-the-gson-converter